# How to access files via localhost in firefox browser

Tags: file-system, firefox-for-android

I'm looking for a way to access my devices files in Firefox. The reason for this is I want to use an extension to read *.md file.

I know that I can use `file:///` to access files, but the extension can't use this way. The only way is to use localhost. I have searched around but have only found talk about accessing the PC via localhost. I want to access the local android files.

Here is the link to the extension I want to use: [Markdown Viewer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/markdown-viewer-chrome/?src=search)

Comment: I think, *files* you can see with `file:///` URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around a little and trying out some options (especialy from Firelord), I decided to actually try to use `file:///`, and to my great surprise it worked, even though the instructions for the add-on says it doesn't.

So to answer the question, you can access the files by using `file:///`. This is much easier then having to install and setup another app.

Answer (score 3):

If you need localhost, than run a web server on your Android and bind it to loopback address. There are many apps on Play Store that can run a web server. I just tested out [HTTP Server powered by Apache](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.esminis.server.apache) and it works fine.

Instructions:

1. Install and launch it.
2. Grant Storage permission/access.
3. Download an Apache version. The latest version comes with the app and would be marked with **X** sign next to it. Tap on that entry once to install that version.
4. Afterwards, go to the section *Server address & port* → Change:

   - Server Address: 127.0.0.1
   - Server Port: 8080 (or anything above 1024)
   - Fallback action: Stop
5. Start Server. The server's home directory is `/sdcard/htdocs/public/`, so move your directories under public directory.
6. Setup your addon in Firefox and add `http://127.0.0.1` under Allowed Origins as mentioned [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c7Lb_Y092ok&feature=youtu.be).
7. Load your file in Firefox by using the address `http://127.0.0.1:PORT/PATH. The extension should work now.

Replace PORT with the port you used for the server. Replace PATH with the path of your directory/file relative to public directory. So, if  file is under `/sdcard/htdocs/public/testing/readme.md`, the PATH should be `testing/readme.md`.

**Note:** for some reason the addon sometimes load, other times it just shows a blank page when trying to load README.md.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do this by simply installing Apache Web Server in [Termux](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details%3Fid%3Dcom.termux%26hl%3Den_IN%26referrer%3Dutm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dorganic%2526utm_term%253Dtermux%26pcampaignid%3DAPPU_1_Q9VoXPuMKIWLr7wP6q2U-AI&ved=2ahUKEwi7up6B6sHgAhWFxYsBHeoWBS8Q5YQBMAB6BAgKEAI&usg=AOvVaw3rhUSf-YOdA2zJIMxKG6ne). So after installing Termux. Do the following steps:-

1. `apt update && apt upgrade -y`
2. `apt install apache2`

It will install Apache Web Server in your Termux
Then do `apachectl start` it will start the Apache server.

You might see a Warning like this:-

> AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

To correct this : just uncomment the line 221:

which says `# ServerName
www.example.com:8080`

And then place your `/sdcard` in your
 web root:

(`/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/apache2/default-site/htdocs/`)

by doing

`cp -r /sdcard /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/apache2/default-site/htdocs/`

Then point to:

`https://127.0.0.1:8080/sdcard` in your browser.

Now, you will be able to access your files in your browser.

Comment: I would like to be able to access the sdcard on a steady basis. Besides that copying it takes a long time, and waists a lot of space.

Comment: @Sruly It will not _actually_ copy `/sdcard` instead it will create a symlink like this:- `sdcard -> /storage/self/primary` in your webroot and it takes no time and extra space

Comment: OK thanks that clarifies it. I thought because of the `-r` that it copies it, thanks for the clarification.